# Module Pygame has no init member?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame

I am trying to import and use pygame:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
```

I use Visual Studio Code and I get the issue saying "Module 'pygame' has no 'init' member".

I have already tried to edit the settings with multiple versions of this:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
"----extension-pkg-whitelist=1xml"
]
```

But it does not work for me. Is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: You have most likely named your script (or some other script) `pygame.py`, so that it's being imported instead of the actual `pygame` module.  If this is the case, doing `import pygame; print(pygame.__file__)` will show the location of the offending file.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered that before. But I just checked and it imports the correct pygame. No other script named that.

Comment: What does `dir(pygame)` show? If it doesn't show an `init` attribute then it doesn't exist on the module you're importing named `pygame` (you can look at `pygame.__file__` to see exactly which file Python is importing for that name).